# Django FileSystemStorage.url is wrong

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-file-upload, file-system-storage

Code:

```
company = Company.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.POST:
        company_name = request.POST['company_name']

        company_logo = request.FILES['company_logo']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/home/ubuntu/mywebsite/media/company/' + str(company.pk) + '/')
        filename = fs.save(company_logo.name, company_logo)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
```

`fs.url` returns: `/media/thefilename.png` which is wrong ... apparently the `.url` method doesn't take in to account what you've set your `location` attribute to?

How do I ensure that the correct path is being returned?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem, so to complet what @alfonso.kim said, I had to specify both `base_url` and `location`. with your code it would be something like this

```
company = Company.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.POST:
        company_name = request.POST['company_name']

        company_logo = request.FILES['company_logo']

        dir_storage = '/home/ubuntu/mywebsite/media/company/' + str(company.pk) + '/'
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=dir_storage , base_url = dir_storage )
        filename = fs.save(company_logo.name, company_logo)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
```

Old thread, but hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/storage/):

> **base_url**
>
> URL that serves the files stored at this location. Defaults to the value of your MEDIA_URL setting.

you are setting the location of the storage, while `url` is defaults to `MEDIA_URL`. If you want to serve user uploaded files check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342410/how-to-serve-user-uploaded-files-in-django).

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
            //settings.py
            MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
            MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
            //end of settings.py

            //this one is for save the image to preferred directory
            logoRoot = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images/')

            //this is for accessing the image after you save it
            logo_url = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, 'images/')

            logoRoot=logoRoot.replace("\\","/")


            fs = FileSystemStorage(location=logoRoot)
            filename = fs.save(company_logo.name, company_logo)


            //image url, don't use fs.url(filename) to get image url instead use code 
            below

            uploaded_file_url = logo_url+filename
```

Comment: Please explain your issue.